# Hadoop showing old version despite latest version installation

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, microsoft-distributed-file-system

I am trying to install hadoop in my ubuntu OS. I followed each and every step exactly from this link [Hadoop Install Tutorial](http://codesfusion.blogspot.com/2013/10/setup-hadoop-2x-220-on-ubuntu.html) and everything was going as expected until i tried to run 
`$ start-dfs.sh` and `$ hadoop jar ./share/hadoop/mapreduce/hadoop-mapreduce-examples-2.2.0.jar pi 2 5` command. These commands doesn't work as expected.I tried R&D and somehow came to know that i was using older hadoop version `Hadoop 1.0.2` despite of me getting latest 2.2.0 version.

As i could not solve this, i tried to uninstall hadoop completely, Now when i try doing it, it says

```
$ sudo dpkg -r hadoop
dpkg: dependency problems prevent removal of hadoop:
 hadoop-native depends on hadoop (= 1.0.2-0ubuntu1~hadoop1).
dpkg: error processing hadoop (--remove):
 dependency problems - not removing
Errors were encountered while processing:
 hadoop
```

Appreciate any help !

Answer (score 0):

I dont know whether its a proper way to remove hadoop or not, but i have removed it using below method.

1. I first manually deleted the `/usr/local/hadoop` folder from all the users(If any).If you are not able to remove it due to lack of permissions, then make sure about the permissions of the folder. Make the permission of the folder to "Sudo" and on "Creating and deleting files" so that every user can delete from their instances.

Then from Terminal `$ rm -r hadoop` does the job going to the `/usr/local` path.

After this, i checked `$ hadoop version` again in terminal ..and boom it again showed its existence. Then i did below step.

2.Goto terminal `sudo apt-get purge hadoop` or `sudo apt-get remove hadoop`...then it worked